# (Closed) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'download' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, download, typeerror

**IMPORTANT: Google fixed this issue in Chrome 27.0.1448.0 dev-m**

I've written a Chrome Extension that extracts certain url's from currently viewed site and then downloads a subset of them. The extension is based on the "Download Selected Links" sample on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html. **For the last 3 months my code worked.** Last time I used it was 2 days ago - and today I started getting

**Problem:**

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'download' of undefined*

when trying to download a url on the line

```
chrome.downloads.download(
    {url: visibleLinks[i],filename: visibleNames[i] + '.mp3'},
    function(id) { 
        pending = pending - 1;
        if (pending == 0) {
            window.close();
        };
    }
);
```

Needed permissions in the manifest file seem to be included:

```
"permissions": [
    "downloads", "tabs", "https://*/*", "http://*/*"
]
```

**What I use:**

- latest dev-version of Chrome: 27.0.1444.3 dev-m (same issue was also seen in 27.0.1438.7 dev-m)

**What I tried:**

- Logging url and filename passed to chrome.downloads.download call. Both are ok.
- Searching for similar problems on forums. Unfortunately, I can't find a problem in my code (or at least a clue where to begin with).
- Downloading the sample "Download Selected Links" extension from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html and trying to use it (after replacing its 0-byte icon.png with some other icon). Result: it just reproduces the bug.

**Same problem, different posts:**

- Dated 10.12.2012: [How do I enable the "chrome.downloads" api on the dev or canary channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431075/)
- Dated 15.03.2013: [Download url chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806908/)

**Issues posted to Google:**

- Started: 16.03.2013 by Garrett: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=202178
  Status: merged with (look below)
- Started: 16.03.2013 by QuteBits: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=221952
  Status: fixed (21.03.2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google seems to have borked something with the downloads API in the latest release.  I have been experiencing a similar issue with my own extension since the update.  The only solution is to wait until they release a fix for it. Sorry :(

**Edit:**
I have submitted a bug report to Google.  You can follow that [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=202178)

Comment: Seems they've updated dev channel exactly 2 days ago (14.03). What bothers me though - the Google blog [states](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.de/) the newest release is 27.0.1438.8 and my Chrome shows me I have 27.0.1438.7 dev-m (it also says it's the latest release).

Comment: @QuteBits The Canary version seems to be having the same issue, I hope Google fixes it soon. :(

Comment: The issue you've posted is unfortunately still "Unconfirmed" by Google (whatever that means). Guess we need to get their attention somehow.

Comment: @QuteBits Any ideas as to how?

Comment: I guess by calling/writing to people working on Chrome at Google (linking them to this or the issue page).

Comment: @QuteBits I don't exactly live in a country that makes doing either of those easy tasks.

Comment: I just emailed them - I guess something is moving now (look at the issue that I posted with you at the same day)

Comment: ok, they confirmed they are investigating it from now on. Hope Google cracks this easily :)

Comment: they fixed it (though now there is another bug - but this issue is fixed). Thanks for your quick initial assumption (that it was a Chrome bug) and support :)

Comment: downloads not appearing in the download bar (2h ago they posted a new issue for that). Btw, if u want to chat, you can write me at qute.bits@gmail.com